# Azure Functions - New-AzContainerGroup : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-container-instances

I've been trying to create Azure Container instance using http triggered powershell Azure Function.

I've wrote some code and it works... kind of

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$appId = "appID"
$appPassword = "appPassword"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $appPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$mycred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($appId, $secpasswd)

$status = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName "test" -Name "testName" `
    -Image "imageName" `
    -RegistryCredential $mycred `
    -RestartPolicy Never

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```

When i hit endpoint, i always get 500 response code, but for some reason container instance is being created anyway and it works. Here's error from terminal:

```
Executed 'Functions.testFuntion' (Failed, Id=240084c5-6aa2-4207-ae84-66f85a03504b)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.testFuntion. 
System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack: 
at 
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Utility.TypeExtensions.
DeriveContentType(HttpResponseContext  
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Utility.TypeExtensions.DeriveContentType
(HttpResponseContext httpResponseContext, RpcHttp rpcHttp) in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell- 
worker\src\Utility\TypeExtensions.cs:line 196
at 
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Utility.TypeExtensions.ToRpcHttp(HttpResponseContext 
httpResponseContext) in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell- 
worker\src\Utility\TypeExtensions.cs:line 188
at 
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Utility.TypeExtensions.ToTypedData(Object value) in 
C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\Utility\TypeExtensions.cs:line 242
at 
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.RequestProcessor.BindOutputFromResult(InvocationResponse 
response, AzFunctionInfo functionInfo, Hashtable results) in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell- 
worker\src\RequestProcessor.cs:line 465
at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.RequestProcessor.ProcessInvocationRequestImpl
(StreamingMessage request, AzFunctionInfo functionInfo, PowerShellManager psManager,
FunctionInvocationPerformanceStopwatch stopwatch)
in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\RequestProcessor.cs:line 305.
```

Is this something i should be worried about? Even though i get 500 response, everything seems to be working.

Comment: It seems the error caused by your application in the image. There is something wrong with it. You must find it yourself, or show the code of your application.

Comment: Result is exactly the same when i run hello-world image without any additional parameters

Comment: Do you check your application only and what about it? You need to make it work well first of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define $body before using it in the Push-OutputBinding response.

Something like:

```
$body = "My Message"
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```